# vite build rollupOptions.external error: when i try to make vue and vuetify external and run vite,the vite doesnt work?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vite

My devDependencies

- "sass": "^1.33.0",
- "vite": "^2.1.2",
- "vite-plugin-html": "^2.0.7",
- "vite-plugin-vue2": "^1.4.2",
- "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",

My vite.config.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')
const path = require('path')
const { createVuePlugin } = require('vite-plugin-vue2')
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const { injectHtml } = require('vite-plugin-html')
const package = require('./package.json')


const resolve = (dir) => path.join(__dirname, dir)

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'vuetify']
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    createVuePlugin(),
    injectHtml({
      injectData: {
        title: package.title
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },

  server: {
    port: 3000,

  }
})
```

and I import the vue and vuetify in index.html

```html
<script type="module" src="/webapp/main.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

But it return error .

```
...
    node_modules\vuetify\src\styles\settings\_variables.scss 64:11  @import
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
the main scss file with: mixing, vars and other scss
/src/styles/my-app-style.scss

```html
<style lang="scss">
@import "./src/styles/my-app-style.scss";
</style>
```